# Bad Access Code 1 when using a Singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton, exc-bad-access

I need some help.

I'm using this singleton pattern within an iOS application I'm developing:

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Item;

@interface ItemManager : NSObject

- (id)init;
+ (ItemManager *)sharedInstance;

- (int)ratingFromObjectName:(NSString *)objectName;

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *itemArray;

@end
```

.m file

```
static ItemManager *sharedInstance = nil; 

+ (ItemManager *)sharedInstance
{

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[ItemManager alloc] init];

});
return sharedInstance;
    }

    - (int)ratingFromObjectName:(NSString *)objectName {

for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.count; i++) {
    if ([[[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] itemName] isEqualToString:objectName]) { //This is the line that throws bad access code 1
        NSLog(@"Found: %@ Returned: %d", [[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] ratingAverage], 
              [[[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] ratingAverage] intValue]);

        return [[[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] ratingAverage] intValue];
    }
}
return 0;
    }
```

I get bad access when I use this in another class:

```
 int rating = [[ItemManager sharedInstance] ratingFromObjectName:bla];
```

The bla object being sent is a NSString that is definitely working, it is 100% not the issue, as I have tested this. Removing the sharedInstance method and creating an array every time seems to work, however my attempt for this singleton is to avoid that, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I have commented on the line returning the error.

Regards, WA

Comment: what kind of object is "`bla`"?  Also, are you getting the correct values from your "`NSLog`" printed out in your console?

Comment: Bla is a string, it is working correctly if I keep creating an instance of ItemManager, but this is not what I want, I need a singleton so it on init once.

Comment: Why do you even need a singleton?, it looks like this could be achieved with a class method.

Comment: the manager has the property array of items, these will be used multiple times in different classes. The array is init via JSON so I do not want to keep init

Comment: where is variable `itemName` come from? you mean `objectName`? also try enable NSZombie

Comment: Sorry, typo, its objectName.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out which line of code is throwing the bad access. Is it the `sharedInstance` method or `ratingFromObjectName:`. I would first change the calling code to

```
ItemManager *manager = [ItemManager sharedInstance];
int rating = [manager ratingFromObjectName:bla];
```

As that will help with isolating the problem.

Secondly, I would also consider not using the Singleton pattern unless really necessary is iOS apps. It's been my experience that it is often overused (and in the Java world), and whilst convenient, can make writing unit tests more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, but a singleton would be required for the nature of the application I am developing. As shown in the original message; I have highlighted the line resulting in the error by a comment.